# PostgreSQL query plan with LIMIT

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance, sql-limit

If the actual result of a query would join a lot of data (like when `searchterm` is short or a frequent city name, below), limiting the output of that query with limit does not improve execution time and actually results in awful performance:

[image]

However, if the data to join is small, execution time is obviously great:

[image]

Now, if Postgres knows in advance that the output will contain at most 25 rows, why is there such a terrible execution performance? How can I re-write my query?

```
SELECT addritems.plz
FROM   addritems
      INNER JOIN adresse ON adresse.adrcd = addritems.adrcd
      INNER JOIN strasse ON adresse.skz = strasse.skz
                        AND adresse.gkz = strasse.gkz
      INNER JOIN ortschaft ON adresse.okz = ortschaft.okz
                         AND adresse.gkz = ortschaft.gkz
      INNER JOIN gemeinde ON adresse.gkz = gemeinde.gkz
WHERE  search @@ to_tsquery(plainto_tsquery('german', 'searchterm')::text || ':*')limit 25;
```

Comment: As strange as it sounds, having a `LIMIT` clause can badly affect the performance, when you  have no or not proper `ORDER` clause. Read [this answer on DBA StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19726/slow-order-by-with-limit/19744#19744)

Comment: Questions about performance need to provide a minimum of essential information. Obviously, your version of Postgres to begin with. You did not even table-qualify `search` to let us see where that's from. Also, we prefer the text of a query plan over pasted images. If the query plan is huge, upload to explain.depesz.com. Consider instructions in the tag [\[postgresql-performance\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). The answer Thomas linked to may or may not work for you.